# Can I define a C++ lambda function without auto?

Tags: c++, lambda

I have plenty of C# experience before but I am new to C++. I have seen this problem when trying to use lambda as I used to do.

For example:

```
auto compare = [] (int i1, int i2) { return i1*2 > i2; }
```

Is there any way to define the lambda with a specific type, rather than auto deduction?

I am asking this because I want to define a common lambda for my class. This lambada will be used in multiple places so I don't want to define them multiple times. However, 'auto' can only be used on static members, while on the other hand, I want to access non-static fields in the lambda.

Comment: Try using [std::function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/function/function/).

Comment: You can access non-static fields by capturing `this`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You use `std::function`, which can glob any lambda or function pointer.

`std::function< bool(int, int) > myFunc = []( int x, int y ){ return x > y; };`

See [C++ Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Comment: Note that `std::function` is less efficient because of the dynamicism. Usually doesn't matter.

Comment: @siyu less efficient than lambdas, but more efficient than pretty much any other language's equivalent abstraction.  1.5-3x the call overhead of a function pointer last I checked (vtable lookup then call).  There are `std::function` implememtations that rivsl function pointers, but not in major libraries that I know of.

Comment: If you're so worried about the performance hit of std::function then there's probably better questions to ask like why you're using lambdas in a performance sensitive environment.

Comment: @MorphingDragon Why do you think lambdas are slow? They can be *pretty* fast, given the fact that modern compilers can inline most of them.

Comment: @morp what?  lambdas should be used in performance sensitive environments: they let you use really complex harnesses to deliver code packages with next to zero overhead.  Why do you think they should not be used?

Comment: Lambda is not slow at all.

Comment: I never claimed lambdas were "slow". But if your performance requirements are at the point where std::function is actually a concern why would you encourage std::function use by using lambdas in your code?

Comment: @MorphingDragon Because std::function is way slower than (most) lambdas. std::function may very well be a concern. It's best use case is when you need to store *any callable* of a given signature in a variable (e.g. member) without the need to make it a template parameter (which would be the best case). However, putting performance aside, std::function is the *most concise, readable and safe way* to store or pass a function around, whether it is a lambda or not.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `std::function`, but if that's not going to be efficient enough, you could write a functor object which resembles what lambdas do behind the scenes:

```
auto compare = [] (int i1, int i2) { return i1*2 > i2; }
```

is almost the same as

```
struct Functor {
    bool operator()(int i1, int i2) const { return i1*2 > i2; }
};
Functor compare;
```

If the functor should capture some variable in the context (e.g. the "this" pointer), you need to add members inside the functor and initialize them in the constructor:

```
auto foo = [this] (int i) { return this->bar(i); }
```

is almost the same as

```
struct Functor {
    Object *that;
    Functor(Object *that) : that(that) {}
    void operator()(int i) const { return that->bar(i); }
};
Functor foo(this);
```

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this without the overhead of `std::function`, if you feel a functor is too cumbersome, is to use function pointers, a typedef, and optionally a macro.

In your example, this function pointer would look like this:

```
bool (*compare)(int, int) = [] (int i1, int i2) { return i1*2 > i2; };
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Note how `compare`, the pointer's identifier, is tucked into the parenthesis, this trips people up sometimes, but it's the proper way to declare a function pointer.

You can write a typedef in the same way:

```
typedef bool (*Compare)(int, int);
```

The typedef name is where the identifier would ordinarily be.  This allows you to now write the more concise:

```
Compare func = [] (int i1, int i2) { return i1*2 > i2; };
^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If you allow yourself to use macros, you can go even further in terms of ergonomics:

```
#define CompareLambda [](int i1, int i2)
typedef bool (*Compare)(int, int);
...
Compare func = CompareLambda{ return i1*2 > i2;};
```

Macros and typedefs exist as tools to make your work as a programmer easier by helping you avoid repeating yourself, don't be afraid to use them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as `std::function<Signature>` as mentioned, but at the cost of type-erasing the lambda. This will add an indirection (basically a virtual function call) when you call your lambda. So keep in mind it is less efficient if you will use it in a context where this matters.